# Legends Lost quest stuck (already have Sunder and Wraithguard)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have this quest opened saying I need to find the detoured caravans.
I wasn't finding anything, than I looked it up on the internet. I've already found those long ago, already completed the quest, and have the items rewarded.

> I remember defeating the ebony centurion and the items are in my house in Solitude: the mannequins have the gauntlets.

I don't know if it reopened or never closed. Is there a way to force complete it with no consequences? I just want to remove it from my journal.

I'm playing an unmodded Anniversary Edition.

Comment: Do any of the [bugs listed on the UESP wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Legends_Lost#Bugs) cover your situation?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy nope..